# Replacing Default Item Numbers by Enumerated Tcolorbox Logos

Tags: pdftex, lists, enumerate, tcolorbox, logos

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=blue,
    colback=blue!30,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}

\begin{document}

\Large
\begin{enumerate}
\item I would like to have LateX automatically replace the default item number by $\logo{1}$
\\[10pt]
\item I would like to have LateX automatically replace the default item number by $\logo{2}$
\\[10pt]
\item I would like to have LateX automatically replace the default item number by $\logo{3}$
\\[10pt]
\item And so on \ldots\
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

QUESTION: I would like to replace the default enumerate item numbers 1., 2., 3., ... by the enumerated `tcolorbox` logos as shown. How may I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `enumitem` package and `\begin{enumerate}[label=\logo{\arabic*}]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=blue,
    colback=blue!30,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}


\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{enumerate}[label=\logo{\arabic*}]
\item I would like to have LateX automatically replace the default item number by $\logo{1}$
\\[10pt]
\item I would like to have LateX automatically replace the default item number by $\logo{2}$
\\[10pt]
\item I would like to have LateX automatically replace the default item number by $\logo{3}$
\\[10pt]
\item And so on \ldots\
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your code, may I presume that the *a* beneath `\Large` should be replaced by `\begin{enumerate}[label=\logo{\arabic*}]`?

Comment: @Garfunkel: Thanks for making me aware of this copy-past-error. I have corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.